# How can I take comma separated inputs for python AnyTree module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, anytree

**Community**. I need to accept multiple comma-separated inputs to produce a summary of information ( specifically, how many different employees participated in each group/project)? The program takes employees, managers and groups in the form of strings.

I'm using anytree python library to be able to search/count the occurrence of each employee per group. However, this program is only accepting one value/cell at a time instead of multiple values.

**Here is the tree structure and how I accept input values?**

```
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Joe
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Manager1
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Group1
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Charles 
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Manager1
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Group2
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Joe
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Manager3
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Group1
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Charles
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Manager3
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Group1
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Joe
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Manager5
Press q to exit, Enter your data: Group2
Press q to exit, Enter your data: q
Employee   No of groups
   JOE       2
   CHARLES       2
Group
├── GROUP1
│   ├── JOE
│   │   └── MANAGER1
│   ├── JOE
│   │   └── MANAGER3
│   └── CHARLES
│       └── MANAGER3
└── GROUP2
    ├── CHARLES
    │   └── MANAGER1
    └── JOE
        └── MANAGER5
```

I need help with this code so that It can accept comma-separated values; for example, to enter **Joe, Manager1, Group1** at a time.

```
import anytree

from anytree import Node, RenderTree, LevelOrderIter, LevelOrderGroupIter, PreOrderIter

import sys

# user input
io=''
lst_input = []
while (io!='q'):
    io=input('Press q to exit, Enter your data: ')
    if io!='q':
        lst_input.append(io.upper())

# change list in to matrix
lst=[]
for i in range(0, len(lst_input), 3):
    lst.append(lst_input[i:i + 3])

lst

# create tree structure from lst
group = Node('Group')
storeGroup = {}
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][2] in [x.name for x in group.children]: # parent already exist, append childrens
        storeGroup[lst[i][0]] = Node(lst[i][0], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][2]])
        storeGroup[lst[i][1]] = Node(lst[i][1], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][0]])
    else: # create parent and append childreds
        storeGroup[lst[i][2]] = Node(lst[i][2], parent=group)
        storeGroup[lst[i][0]] = Node(lst[i][0], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][2]])
        storeGroup[lst[i][1]] = Node(lst[i][1], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][0]])


store = {}
for children in LevelOrderIter(group, maxlevel=3):
    if children.parent!=None and children.parent.name!='Group':
        if children.name not in store:
            store[children.name] = {children.parent.name}
        else:
            store[children.name] = store[children.name] | {children.parent.name}

print('Employee', '  No of groups')
for i in store:
    print('   '+i+'      ', len(store[i]))


for pre,fill, node in RenderTree(group):
    print('{}{}'.format(pre,node.name))
```

Thank you! Any thoughts are welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leverage unpacking to extract elements. Then the if statement can be re-written this way.

```
if io!='q':
    name, role, grp = io.upper(). split(',')
    lst_input.append([name,role, grp])
```

you also need to change `lst.append(lst_input[i:i + 3])` in the for loop to this.

```
lst.append(lst_input[0][i:i + 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe one way to go about it is:

```py
name, role, grp = io.upper().split(',')
```

which for an input such as `Joe, Manager1, Group1`

```
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> name, role, grp = input("Press q to exit, Enter your data:").split(",")
Press q to exit, Enter your data:Joe, Manager1, Group1
>>> name
'Joe'
>>> role
' Manager1'
>>> grp
' Group1'
```

Would that work for you ?

Comment: It seems to be a good approach but raising the ValueError exception.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lst` output is something like:

```
[['Joe', 'Manager1', 'Group1'], ['Charles', 'Manager1', 'Group2'], ['Joe', 'Manager3', 'Group1'], ['Charles', 'Manager3', 'Group1'], ['Joe', 'Manager5', 'Group2']]
```

The below code makes the same `lst` output with a much better performance:

```
import anytree

from anytree import Node, RenderTree, LevelOrderIter, LevelOrderGroupIter, PreOrderIter

import sys

# user input
lst = []
while True:
   io=input('Press q to exit, Enter your data: ')
   if io!='q':
      lst.append(io.upper().split(',')) 
   else:
      break
print(lst)

# create tree structure from lst
group = Node('Group')
storeGroup = {}
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][2] in [x.name for x in group.children]: # parent already exist, append childrens
        storeGroup[lst[i][0]] = Node(lst[i][0], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][2]])
        storeGroup[lst[i][1]] = Node(lst[i][1], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][0]])
    else: # create parent and append childreds
        storeGroup[lst[i][2]] = Node(lst[i][2], parent=group)
        storeGroup[lst[i][0]] = Node(lst[i][0], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][2]])
        storeGroup[lst[i][1]] = Node(lst[i][1], parent=storeGroup[lst[i][0]])


store = {}
for children in LevelOrderIter(group, maxlevel=3):
    if children.parent!=None and children.parent.name!='Group':
        if children.name not in store:
            store[children.name] = {children.parent.name}
        else:
            store[children.name] = store[children.name] | {children.parent.name}

print('Employee', '  No of groups')
for i in store:
    print('   '+i+'      ', len(store[i]))


for pre,fill, node in RenderTree(group):
    print('{}{}'.format(pre,node.name))
```

Defining a lot of unnecessary lists in your original code will ruin your performance. Even avoid doing the extra comparision or defining unnecessary variables. Note that we don't have `do ... while` structure in `Python`. So, we use `break` to avoid doing duplicate comparision.